# Regex string with three wildcards, replace with second and third only

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext

I have multiple `<li>` in my code, well over 3,000 of them (don't ask!).

They are all either in the format:

`<li>Name, Job, Company</li>`

or

`<li>Job, Company</li>`

I need to find the ones that contain a `Name` (i.e. the ones with two commas `,`, as opposed to just one), and remove the names. I was hoping to use Sublime Text's Regex find+replace feature.

Now, I can select all the lines that contain two commas using the following regex:

`<li>.*,.*,.*</li>`

But how do I now replace those with just the second and third `.*`s, discarding the first?

Comment: Use capture groups in the regexp, and back-references in the replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find this :

```
<li>.*,(.*),(.*)</li>
```

replace with :

```
<li>\1,\2</li>
```

or

```
<li>$1,$2</li>
```

whatever your editor supports

Comment: Capture Groups... perfect light-reading for this evening, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/[^,]*,([^,]*,[^,]*)/\1/g'
```

**not** `.*` because it would match the comma.